# What does cache-queue-take mean in Volley and why it takes in my case so long?

Tags: android, android-volley

I´m new to Android and i´m making an app that from latitude and longitude gets the address. But the problem is the response of Volley, it takes too long to get the response in my Response.Listener.
The code is the following:

```
private void obtenerDireccionFromLatLng(final double lat,final double lng) {
       tm.log("BEGIN_VOLLEY");
       RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MapsFijarPosicion.this);

        String url = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=%1$f,%2$f&sensor=true&language="
                + Locale.getDefault().getCountry(), lat, lng);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, createMyReqSuccessListener(),
                                                                                createMyReqErrorListener());
        queue.add(stringRequest);
       tm.log("END_VOLLEY");
    }
```

and the Response.Listener is here:

```
private Response.Listener<String> createMyReqSuccessListener() {
        return new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                tm.log("BEGIN_PARSING");
                List<Address> retList=new ArrayList<Address>();
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
                    if("OK".equalsIgnoreCase(jsonObject.getString("status"))){

                        JSONArray results=jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
                        for(int i=0;i<results.length();i++){
                            JSONObject result = results.getJSONObject(i);
                            String indiStr = result.getString("formatted_address");
                            Address addr = new Address(Locale.getDefault());
                            addr.setAddressLine(0, indiStr);
                            retList.add(addr);

                        }

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mUbicacion=retList.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnGuardarPosicion.setEnabled(true);
                tm.log("END_PARSING");
            }
        };
    }
```

Trace output:

http://subefotos.com/ver/?5a667e29104374bfbebda184d81dd19ao.png

Volley log output:

http://subefotos.com/ver/?387ed0867bd266fa734f43a7706f7761o.png

Thanks in advanced.